# Map/snap GPX erroneuous lat-lon points to edges

Tags: pandas, geopandas, shapely, osmnx

I have several (25*10) GPX cycling traces that I want to analyse (distances, max speeds, acceleration, ...), obtained from Runkeeper. The issue is that the data contains significant errors, with data points in fields rather than on roads. I'm new to geospatial analysis, so I'm *aware* that packages such as geopandas and shapely exist, yet I'm nowhere near the point where I know which packages I should be using all of the time.

The solution to my main problem appears to be similar to that suggested by the paper of Schuessler, N. and K.W. Axhausen (2009): Map-matching of GPS traces on high-resolution navigation networks using the Multiple Hypothesis Technique (MHT), https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/baug/ivt/ivt-dam/vpl/reports/501-600/ab568.pdf

So far, the closest that I've gotten to downloading, plotting and analysing map data is using the [osmnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx) package, which avoids having to use for-pay services (e.g. Google's [snap-to-road feature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) which also can only handle 100 points at a time). I've converted the GPX data to a pandas dataframe using gpxpy, which gives me a df which contains time, lat, lon and elevation data.

I would like to snap each GPX point that is obviously incorrect (road width + tolerance of e.g. 20 m) to the road (=an edge). My problem is that I don't understand the osmnx package well enough to do what I want to do.

When I do

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import gpxpy
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

#df is created using gpxpy to convert GPX data to a list, which is then converted to a pandas DataFrame

delta = 0.035 #in degrees, for plotting bounds
N = max(df['lat'][0],df['lat'][-1]) + delta
S = min(df['lat'][0],df['lat'][-1]) - delta
E = max(df['lon'][0],df['lon'][-1]) + delta
W = min(df['lon'][0],df['lon'][-1]) - delta

G = ox.graph_from_bbox(N, S, E, W, network_type='drive')

route_edges = ox.get_nearest_edges(G,df['lon'],df['lat'],method='balltree',dist=0.0001)
```

the content of "route_edges" is an ndarray which contains numbers which are likely projected (to WGS84 or UTM?), rather than in degrees. I don't know how to convert either the ndarray back to degrees, or get the lat/lon GPX trace values in the format of the ndarray, so I can calculate the distance to a road and determine whether to keep or replace the data.

To summarise:
My main problem is snapping/correcting incorrect GPX data to known roads, for which I'd prefer to use OpenStreetMap data.

Subproblems:

- Should I use osmnx to calculate distance between a GPX (lat/lon) point and an edge, or should I use geopandas or shapely (or something else entirely?)?
- How can I convert a lat/lon point to a projected format as used within osmnx (e.g. `G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)`), so I can state the distance for the get_nearest_edges method in metres rather than degrees?

Comment: Pysal Spaghetti can do that https://pysal-spaghetti.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and momepy has a script which does similar thing, so you can dig into the code https://docs.momepy.org/en/latest/generated/momepy.get_network_id.html#momepy.get_network_id

Comment: @martinfleis thank you. I've ended up using Shapely's `distance` and `nearest_point` functionality to calculate distances and correct (=snap) points to the edge. The following [link](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/269) on OSMNX's github page also illustrated some of the code. (I didn't know how to access a feature such as "G.node[n]['y']").

Comment: This notebook https://heidimhurst.github.io/assets/networks/coursework.html demonsrates an extension to `osmnx` that parses gpx files and tries to reconcile routes over the OSM network; gpx.py code at https://github.com/heidimhurst/osmnx/blob/master/osmnx/gpx.py

Comment: @psychemedia thank you; that is an awesome workbook. I'll see how I can use it.